# Spring @Autowire another implementation of the current service

Tags: java, spring

I need to have an interface and then two implementations in different maven modules. Both impl services see api modul with interface but they don't see each other.

There is a default implementation and then transactional implementation. I want transactional impl service just load and call default impl service. Like this:

```
package my.app.core.api;
public interface MyService {
    boolean process();
}

package my.app.core.impl
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    @Override
    public boolean process() {
        // do something cool...
    }
}

package my.app.somewhere.else.impl
@Service
@Transactional
public class TransactionalMyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    @Autowire
    private MyService myService;

    @Override
    public boolean process() {
        myService.process();
    }
}
```

Is it possible or do I need to `@Autowire` explicitly `MyServiceImpl` instead of interface? Which means to add maven dependancy to `my.app.somewhere.else.impl.pom`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can give different names to your services like so:

```
@Service
@Qualifier("transactionalMyService")
```

And then when you autowire you can use the name:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("transactionalMyService")
private MyService myService;
```

Comment: This is the right approach, but I just want to point out that you probably want to actually annotate the 'worker' impl, rather than the transactional one.

Comment: Interesting, can you explain why?

Comment: Because they want to feed the 'worker' impl into the transactional one.  Really though, they will want to provide names to both, because the transitional one will need to be bound within the object using the service.

Comment: Is it possible without @Qualifier?

Comment: @JiKra not possible without qualifier that I know of unless you go about creating your own instances via a factory pattern or the like.